# When gpasswd vs usermod/deluser?

Tags: users, user-management, groups

About user and groups administration I found in many tutorials that appear:

- `gpasswd` - to add and delete users to a group
- `usermod`/`deluser` - to add, modify and delete users of a group

What is not very clear is - When `gpasswd` would be mandatory over `usermod`/`deluser` and viceversa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deluser` is a command to delete an user altogether from the system, not to remove an user from group.

There is no `moduser` command, you probably meant `usermod`.

Both with `usermod` and `gpasswd` you can add/remove users to/from group. They are two different ways to achieve the same.

However, you cannot change the user's **primary** group with `gpasswd`. That can be done with `usermod` only. `gpasswd` manages only so called **supplementary** groups. You can view user's primary and supplementary groups with a command: `id -a username`. Sample output:

```
uid=1000(raj) gid=1000(raj) groups=1000(raj),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

The group listed as `gid=` is the user's primary group. `groups=` lists all groups the user belongs to (primary group is first, followed by supplementary groups).

There are also some things (not directly related to group membership) that each of those commands can do. With `usermod` you can modify other attributes of the user (like users' default shell or home directory), and with `gpasswd` you can set a group password, that allows users who are **not** members of the group to temporarily join the group if they know the password.

Comment: "not to remove an user from group" it can only delete a group ;)

Comment: _"deluser is a command to delete an user altogether from the system, not to remove an user from group."_ - Sure it is: `# deluser test adm` -> `Removing user \`test' from group \`adm' ...`. See also [its documentation](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man8/deluser.8.html#Remove%20an%20user%20from%20a%20specific%20group).

Comment: BTW `usermod` can't delete straightforward the secondary groups, but yes, is possible.

Answer (score 4):

It is never mandatory.

As with many tools different Linux systems merged lots of commnands so we have duplicate methods to do the same thing. There is also a `delgroup` and that one does a `deluser --group`.

`deluser` is part of a set of tools from Debian from the `adduser` package that Ubuntu inherited and it can delete only a group with the `--group` option. Other Linux will not have that and those will have to do with `useradd`.

Backwards compatibility is one reason, another was to get large groups of Unix users to start using Linux without the need to learn new commands. Or, as Linux is open, someone adding a feature used in Unix.

Answer (score 2):

The commands you mention apply for different situations. You use them depending on what you want to accomplish.

> The `gpasswd` command is used to **administer** `/etc/group`, and
> `/etc/gshadow`.

Meanwhile `deluser`:

> **remove** a user **or** group from the system

As for `usermod` (not `moduser`):

> **modify** a user account

Answer (score 0):

- `gpasswd`, `groupmod`: group Administrator, it is limited in managing the group only
- `usermod`: root user, the command has far advanced authorization like changing group and user attributes
- `adduser`, `deluser`, `addgroup`, `delgroup`, `usermod`: all of them can only be accessed by the root user and cannot be accessed by the group Administrator,as he might not have such authorization